# Flume connections refused to spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, push, flume

Considering my connection to FLUME with my spark streaming application. I'm working on a cluster with x nodes. Documentation says:

"When your Flume + Spark Streaming application is launched, one of the Spark workers must run on that machine.

Flume can be configured to push data to a port on that machine."

I understood that my spark streaming job must be launched from a possible worker (all nodes are workers but I don't use all of them), and also I have configured flume to push data to a hostname/port that is also a possible worker for my streaming job. Still I get a connection refused to this hostname/port though there is no firewall, it's not used by anything else etc. I'm sure I understood something wrong. Anyone has any idea?

PS1: I'm using Spark 1.2.0
PS2: My code is tested locally and runs as expected
PS3: Probably  I've understood things wrong since I'm quite new to the whole hadoop/spark thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Documentation says that your flume agent must run in a machine that contains a Spark worker, is your case?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how is spark worker defined? A possible worker? Cause spark does not use all machines on a cluster and I cannot know which will use. Flume is configures in a cluster node but the port/machine that the data is pushed is on a machine that is not a worker.

Comment: Check spark configuration in slaves file in the same directory as spark-env.sh if your spark cluster is standalone mode, you should run a worker in the same node as your flume agent or move this agent to a node which run a worker.

Comment: I have a real cluster. And I cannot change the spark configuration. The real question is. Does the flume agent which pushes the data have to be on a (possible) worker? The flume it self works fine generally. Thanks again!!!